# How to make a Grid-like button group?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, button, grid

What I want to do, is to create a group of buttons. I know there is something like a button group, but only for buttons in a line. I want to create a button group, which will look like a UITableView, with several rows and at least 2 columns. I know I have seen something like this in an app, but I can't remember the name at the moment. The button group should look like a grouped UITableView or the preferences "button-table" of the iPhone, but with more than one column.

Answer (score 0):

Add several `UIButton` objects to a `UITableViewCell`. Add titles, actions etc. to each of your buttons.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how can I create more than one column with this method? And also the correct shape? Because the buttons group should look like a common UITableView..

Comment: Maybe you want to look at UIPickerView. It has several columns and they looks like a regulat Table View cell.